# Passing objects to other objects in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, object, constants

I'm starting out with object-oriented programming in MATLAB, and I'm confused on how to best pass objects to other objects, as MATLAB doesn't feature static type definitions.

I have three different classes, all of which include some constants. Now, I want to use the constants defined in two of the classes in the methods of the third class - how should I do this? The classes are in no hierarchy.

So, I'm looking for something like #include in C++.

Problem illustrated below. How to write "*Object1" and "*Object2" references to access const1 and const2?

```
classdef Object1

    properties (Constant)
        const1 = 100;
    end

    methods
        function Obj1 = Object1()
        end
end

classdef Object2

    properties (Constant)
        const2 = 200;
    end

    methods
        function Obj2 = Object2()
        end
end

classdef Object3

    properties (Immutable)
        property3
    end

    methods
        function Obj3 = Object3()
            Obj3.property3 = *Object1.const1 + *Object2.const2;
        end
end
```

Comment: I guess, if you provide an example it would be more clear. Also if you don't have to, don't get involved in OOP in matlab, stick to their more functional, traditional patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I would rather use OOP, because at the moment I have more than 10 global variables in my functional implementation, and not defining them as global I should include many of those constants in many function calls, which seems a bit daunting and also unclear. It would be best to use structs with the functional implementation, I guess, but still I see the constant access restriction as an advantage of the OOP over the functional. But let's see, how the OOP would work with the constants passed between objects, when I get it running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the asterisks, and I think you have what you need.

There are a couple of other syntax errors in your code (replace `Immutable` with `SetAccess = immutable`, and add missing `end`s to the `classdef`s), but once I made those changes, I get:

```
a = Object3
a = 
  Object3

  Properties:
    property3: 300
  Methods
```

In general, to reference a `Constant` property from another class, just prefix the property with the class name (and possibly package name, if the classes are in a package).